# Calling the same jQuery function on click and on keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that I want to call in 2 different events but I have a doubt since the function has a filter click attache to it.

I was thinking in doing something like:

```
$('.tabs1 a', toggleTabsOnKeypress);
$('.tabs1 a', toggleTabsOnClick);
```

This is the function:

```
var iconTabs = function () {
    tabsSetup();
    $('.tabs1 a').not('.footnote').on('click', function() {
        var $this = $(this); // this
        var $anchorsButThis = $('.tabs1 a').not($(this)); // all <a> tags but this
        var $active = $(this).find('img.img-active').is(':visible'); // return true if the img with img-active class is visible
        var $inactive = $(this).find('img.img-inactive').is(':visible');
        var $tabContainer = $(this).parents('.tab-container');
        var $tabId = $(this).data('tab');

        $eightBoxContent.addClass('opaque-bg');
        $tabContainer.find('.icons-tabs a').addClass('inactive');
        $(this).removeClass('inactive');
        $tabContainer.find('.js-hide-containers .icons-container').hide();
        $tabContainer.find('.js-hide-containers .icons-container[data-tab="'+$tabId+'"]').show();

        $anchorsButThis.each(function() { // loop through other <a>
            $(this).removeClass('selected-shown'); // remove selected-shown
            $(this).find('img.img-active').show(); // show active image
            $(this).find('img.img-inactive').hide(); // hide inactive image
        });

        if(!!$active) {   // if active image is visible
            $(this).find('img.img-active').hide(); // hide active image
            $(this).find('img.img-inactive').show(); // show inactive image
        }
        if(!!$inactive) {  // if inactive image is visible
            $(this).find('img.img-active').show(); // show active image
            $(this).find('img.img-inactive').hide(); // hide active image

            $eightBoxContent.removeClass('opaque-bg');
            $('.js-hide-containers .icons-container').hide();
        }

        $(this).toggleClass('selected-shown');  // toggle selected-shown class

    }).filter('.selected-shown').click();
};
```

So, as you see, there is click event at the end of the function.
And I need that function working exactly the same even if you click or keypress the enter key.

Something like:

```
var toggleTabsOnKeypress = function() {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code == 13) {
        // repeat the whole iconTabs function
    };
};
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not at all clear what you are trying to accomplish. Broken code is not a good substitute for a proper explanation

Comment: @charlietfl all I want is to use that same function in a click event and also when the user clicks with the enter key.

Comment: It's not very clear what prevents you from just making a function and using it in both events.

Comment: (1) Stop using the `$` prefix on variables that are not jQuery objects. Use it only for jQuery objects. For example, `$active`, `$inactive`, and `$tabId` should not have the `$` prefix. This won't affect how the code runs, but it will make it less confusing since the convention is to use `$` only for jQuery objects. (2) You don't need `!!` in an `if` expression, better to leave it out. (3) jQuery's `on` method can take a space-separated list of event names, e.g. `$.on('click keypress')...`.

Comment: (4) You're calling `$(this)` over and over again but already have `$this` - use it instead where appropriate. The one exception is in your `$anchorsButThis.each()` callback, since `this` inside the callback is something else. But I don't think you need this `.each()` at all. Simply use `$anchorsButThis.removeClass('selected-shown');` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple events with `on()` and check the event `type` if needed:

Simple example:

```js
$('div').on('click mouseenter', handler).click();


function handler(e) {
  if (e.type === 'mouseenter') {
    console.log('Hovering')
  } else if (e.type === 'click') {
    console.log('I was clicked')
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="padding:40px">
  hover me or click me
</div>
```